# Creating a linked server from SQL Server X64 to text and Excel using the Access driver

Tags: sql-server, 64-bit, etl, linked-server, adhoc

We are now in progress of moving all our production databases from a SQL Server 2005 32 bit instance to a brand new SQL Server 2012 64 bit instance.

one of the main hardships that our developers still suffer is **Linked Servers**.

We have a lot of programs that need to get some data from text, csv or excel files, and the way it's implemented is with a linked server to text files so you can easily throw a select statement to the text file and insert it into a table.

The problem raised that the 32 bit server used the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` driver the files where on a sheared directory that had full permissions for everyone and we never ran into security issues.

On the new 64 bit server we added a linked server with the following syntax:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'TEMP_FILES_1'
    , @srvproduct=N''
    , @provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
    , @datasrc=N'\\SERVER-APP01\BWA\TempFiles'
    , @provstr=N'Text'
```

**Note:**

- The data source is on a network share.
- The MSSQL service runs as the domain administrator account.
- I'm logged in remotely as the domain administrator which is of course a local administrator too.
- The `\\SERVER-APP01\BWA\TempFiles` directory has full access set for everyone.

Now when i run `EXEC sp_testlinkedserver [TEMP_FILES_1]` i get the following error message:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "TEMP_FILES_1" returned message "'\\SERVER-APP01\BWA\TempFiles' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.".
```

This is definitely a security issue, but the funny part is that when i run `xp_cmdshell 'dir \\SERVER-APP01\BWA\TempFiles'` it returns records so obviously the service has access to this folder...

On the other side on my local computer i also have a 64 bit instance with the same linked server and it works like a charm!

I've been crawling around the internet to find a solution to my problem but seems that linked servers to text files is used very little especially with 64 bit.

Comment: `The MSSQL service runs as the domain administrator account.` o_O

Comment: @JonSeigel it's a fact, it should be changed to a domain managed network account, but we didn't do it yet...

Answer (score 0):

We had to copy the file to a drive on the destination SQL Server system before we could read the data as below:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use y: \\[source directory path] [pw] /USER:[active user]'
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'copy y:\[source file] [destination directory]'
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use y: /delete'
```